# Jenkins build history disappeared

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins build history disappeared on multibranch after modifying regular expression and launching multibranch scan.

Is there a method to recover the build history?

Comment: I am also having the same issue, I think,  I need to press "reload" often to get the latest builds visible again.  It's quite annoying.

Comment: any answer to this? I am having same issue.